# How to get credentials from Azure Linux VM (kubernetes cluster) on machine different from where it was created?

Tags: azure, ssh, kubernetes

I need to gain access to Kubernetes cluster in Azure on a Windows Server 2016 machine. I did not create the cluster but I am assigned as Global Admin in the Azure Account. I already made a successful login to the azure account, but not yet to the server. I already installed kubectl CLI in the machine.
Now I need to access the cluster.

I have **.kube/config**, **.ssh/id_rsa** and **.ssh/id_rsa.pub** inside my **C:\Users\Administrator** folder. I have tried the `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa kubectluser@ourDNSname` and I was able to access it. So my private key is good. But, I don't want to work inside the VM. My working directory is supposed to be inside the WinServer2016 machine. I should be able to `kubectl get nodes` and it must return me a table of the 3 VMs.

This is what happens though **(AGAIN, the ssh to VM works, I can do the kubectl commands w/o problem inside the VM)**

```
az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=myRGroup --name=myClusterName
```

returns

```
Authentication failed. Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\main.py", line 36, in main cmd_result = APPLICATION.execute(args) File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\application.py", line 216, in execute result = expanded_arg.func(params) File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 377, in __call__ return self.handler(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 620, in _execute_command reraise(*sys.exc_info()) File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise raise value File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 602, in _execute_command result = op(client, **kwargs) if client else op(**kwargs) File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\command_modules\acs\custom.py", line 776, in k8s_get_credentials _k8s_get_credentials_internal(name, acs_info, path, ssh_key_file) File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\command_modules\acs\custom.py", line 797, in _k8s_get_credentials_internal '.kube/config', path_candidate, key_filename=ssh_key_file) File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\command_modules\acs\acs_client.py", line 72, in secure_copy ssh.connect(host, username=user, pkey=pkey, sock=proxy) File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 416, in connect look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, t.gss_host, File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 701, in _auth raise saved_exception File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 678, in _auth self._transport.auth_publickey(username, key)) File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1447, in auth_publickey return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event) File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\auth_handler.py", line 223, in wait_for_response raise e paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

---

```
kubectl get nodes
```

returns

```
You must be logged in to the server
```

I can't use `kubectl create` or `kubectl set image deployment` because of this.

What do I need to do? What information do I need from the person and machine who/which created the cluster?

Edit:
[image: Actual Image 1]

[image: Actual Image 2]

Comment: Can you refer to this articles::https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/4782; 

https://github.com/Azure/ACS/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

> I have .kube/config, .ssh/id_rsa and .ssh/id_rsa.pub inside my
>   C:\Users\Administrator folder.

The default path to an SSH key file is `~\.ssh\id_rsa`, in Windows, we should specify the path, like this:

```
C:\Users\jason\.ssh>az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=jasonk8s --name jasonk8s --ssh-key-file C:\Users\jason\.ssh\k8s
Merged "jasontest321mgmt" as current context in C:\Users\jason\.kube\config
C:\Users\jason\.ssh>kubectl.exe get nodes
NAME                    STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
k8s-agent-c99b4149-0    Ready     agent     7m        v1.7.7
k8s-master-c99b4149-0   Ready     master    8m        v1.7.7
```

In your scenario, please try to use this script to get credentials:

```
az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=myRGroup --name=myClusterName --ssh-key-file C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\id_rsa
```

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 Could you please list the keys in that folder `administrator\.ssh\`?

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 It seems your ssh key not store in `c:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\id_rsa`, please download your ssh key to your windows foler.

Comment: inside the directory `c:\Users\Administrator\.ssh` are two files, **id_rsa** and **id_rsa.pub**. If I don't have the correct private key inside **id_rsa**, then my second image above should have failed. Instead I was able to `ssh`, therefore I have the correct keys inside there.

Comment: Can you use that ssh key to ssh your acs master?

Comment: yes, I believe that's the one I've shown above in the 2nd image

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 could you please check you clip version? The latest version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160782/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-johnstephen-19).

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 according to your error screenshot, it seems you are try to use another private to get credential, could you please try use `scp` command to download `$HOME/.kube/config` to your local?  About download credentials, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-connect#connect-to-a-kubernetes-cluster).

Comment: @JohnStephen.19 Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)